# How to apply mod to every element in a list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, modulo

I have a function that produces list of integers to which I would like to apply mod so that no element in the list is greater than 25. For example, the list [6,8,18,28,14,25] should return as [6,8,18,2,14,25]. The code so far is as follows.

```
let charIntList = zip ['a'..'z'] [0..25]
let getIntFromList (x:xs) a = if fst x == a then snd x else getIntFromList xs a
charToInt :: Char -> Int
let charToInt a = getIntFromList charIntList a
zipWithPosition :: [Char] -> [(Char, Int)]
let zipWithPosition m = zip m [0..length m]
position :: [(Char, Int)] -> [Int]
let position m = map snd (zipWithPosition m)
messToInt :: [Char] -> [Int]
let messToInt m = map charToInt m
almostVig :: [Int] [Int] -> [Int]
let almostVig m = zipWith (+) (messToInt m) (position m)
adjust :: [Int] -> [Int]
let adjust m = (mod (almostVig m) 26)
```

This code fails to apply mod to every element in the list generated by almostVig. I have tried using zipWith in `adjust` as `let adjust m = zipWith (mod (almostVig m) 26)`, but that also failed. How can I apply `mod` to every element in a list to produce a new list in which no element is greater than 25?

Comment: What is `(Char, Int)..(Char, Int)`? What about `[Int] [Int]`? Appreciate that you add signatures, but these don't make sense. Please write an actual Haskell module that typechecks. And don't add stuff that's not relevant to the questions.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this and self-taught. It was my best guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map):

```
let adjust m = map (`mod` 26) (almostVig m)
```

`map` has type `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`: it takes a function and applies it to a list element-wise.

`` `mod` 26 `` is partial function application: it turns the function `mod` to an operator `` `mod` `` so that it can be used inline, like `` 128 `mod` 26 `` instead of `mod 128 26`, and then partially applies the second argument.

Comment: Worth explaining the operator-section.

Comment: Thank you! I had tried using map, but as 'let adjust m = map mod (almostVig m) 26'.

Comment: @LillianWangler `map` only takes 2 parameters, not 3, so that's why it didn't work when you wrote it that way.

Answer (score 2):

Use list comprehension.

```
[x `mod` 26 | x <- almostVig]
```

This will result in a new list in which all elements will be less than `26`.